# Did the car stunt go wrong in "Silent Night Deadly Night 2"?

Tags: stunts

In a scene in *Silent Night Deadly Night 2*, Ricky shoots an oncoming car, which swerves up onto a mound of dirt, only barely missing Ricky by inches due to a slight sidestep before flipping over and exploding. I would swear that I had read somewhere that the sidestep wasn't even scripted, that the car was supposed to swerve entirely up into the mound of dirt, but missed, necessitating the dodge (which was admittedly awesome). Is there any truth to that the stunt nearly went horribly wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell by the way the car hits the dirt that it's actually a ramp.  2-wheeled gags are pretty common, and there is a degree of danger when you're going to have a stuntman that close to it, but as you noted he was able to sidestep without much effort.

Comment: The two-wheeled stunt wasn't in question. The question was whether the car was supposed to get that close.